# Detect if an optional argument (which may include None) is provided

Tags: python

Is there a better way than the following example to detect if an optional argument has been provided? Even if `None` is provided, we want to return that instead of raising the exception.

Expected results:

```
>>> get_value('key-exists-not')  # default not provided
KeyError
>>> get_value('key-exists-not', None)  # should support arg
None
>>> get_value('key-exists-not', default=None)  # as well as kwarg
None
>>> get_value('key-exists-not', default='')
''
```

Is this the best/recommended way to do it?

```
def get_value(key, default='somerubbishthatwillneverbeused'):
    try:
        return _data[key]
    except KeyError:
        if default != 'somerubbishthatwillneverbeused':
            return default
        raise
```

Comment: That's true, it was a tricky one to search for because it's a bit different to a standard "default value".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a sentinel value; it's a private singleton that you test agains with `is`:

```
_sentinel = object()
def get_value(key, default=_sentinel):
    if default is _sentinel:
         # no other value provided
```

Answer (score 4):

Two options

```
def foobar (**kwargs):
    if 'some_key' in kwargs:
        # it was provided
```

And the other

```
default = object()
def foobar (some_key=default):
    if some_key is default:
        # some_key not specified
```

Comment: I like the second option more, because it doesn't break the function signature.

Comment: Agreed. Saw that one when I was looking through cherrypy's source, it's a nice solution.